# Matrix form of 1D harmonic oscillator eigenfunctions

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, hilbert-space, operators, harmonic-oscillator

I've been asked to find the uncertainty in position for the harmonic oscillator where:
$$\langle\hat x^2\rangle  = \sum_{k}\langle\Psi_{0}|\hat x|\Psi_{k}\rangle\langle \Psi_{k}|\hat x|\Psi_{0}\rangle $$ 
With the closure operator inserted in the sum
for the harmonic oscillator.
I've been given:
$$
\hat x = \sqrt{\frac{\hbar}{2m\omega}}(\hat a + \hat a^\dagger) 
$$
as the matrix elements of $\hat x$ where $\hat a$ and $\hat a^\dagger$ are the lowering and raising operators, respectively.

My question is, what is the matrix representation of the eigenfunctions $\Psi_{0}$ and $\Psi_{k}$, or how do I find them?

Comment: [WP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_harmonic_oscillator#Analytical_questions).

Comment: Do you mean you cannot find the explicit form of $\Psi_k$?  Presumably they are the eigenstates of the system.  Moreover you do not need a matrix representation for $\hat x$ to proceed.  Indeed this matrix is infinite-dimensional but one obviously only need *very few* elements in this case.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to know what the creation and annihilation operators do on the eigenfunctions. E.g., $a^\dagger$ sends $\Psi_k$ to a multiple of $\Psi_{k+1}$ etc...

Comment: But how can I use the creation operator if I don't know what the matrix elements of $\Psi_{k}$ is in the first place? From where i'm sitting it seems like I have to already know the answer to figure out the answer. Is there some assumption about the matrix form of the HO eigenfunctions that i'm missing?

Comment: From the OP it seems that you are already implying that the $\Psi_k$s are the eigenvectors of either the Hamiltonian or the number operator. With that knowledge, you then know how the creation and annihilation operators act on them. Hence, in principle you could derive a representation of all the operators, under the assumption that the $\Psi_k$s are the standard ONB of $\ell^2(\mathbb N)$.

Answer (score 0):

You have to act with the ladder operators on the eigenstates, use the fact that the energy eigenstates are orthogonal to each other $<ψ_{m}|ψ_{n}>=0$ if $n \neq m$ and then the sum will tern into dirac deltas since only few of the $k$ will survive.